# Rails 5 use dynamic css based on params

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

So i have an application that has multi tenancy and i want to change some of the css based on the params i get

basically want to do the white labelling based on the params in the url, or based on routes
so that if i provide i want the black theme , i can just put the blacktheme identifier in the url and if i want the blue theme, i can just provide the theme name in the url

for e.g.

```
htttps://abc.com/bluetheme

htttps://abc.com/blacktheme
```

I have been searching a lot in Rails Asset Pipeline, but it seems that we can only load the dynamic css while running rails app or while deployment

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just add a condition in to the application layout file which will either load a different stylesheet via `stylesheet_link_tag` or you could have it apply a class to the body element indicating dark mode and scope all of your differentiating css under the darkmode class.

You can use the method `original_fullpath` to see what the current url path is to check what theme should be selected. Although I would opt for putting the theme in the users profile settings or in the cookies/local storage since its not great UX to have the users theme switch when they click a link from someone else.